# When I type in something from my array into the Scanner, it is not doing the correct function

Tags: java

When I type in Beef, Pork, Chicken, or Cheeseburger, it should say "Here is your" and then whatever I typed in, while filtering out anything not in the array. It isn't working. Any help? (Yes I am new to Java) Fixed as best I could from feedback, still not working.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class scannerReview {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] array = new String[]{"Beef","Pork","Chicken","Cheeseburger"};
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What do you want for dinner? Your options are Beef, Pork, Chicken, and Cheesebugers. ");
        String food = sc.nextLine();
        if(!food.equals(array[0])){
            System.out.println("You cannot order that!");
        }
        else if(!food.equals(array[1])){
            System.out.println("You cannot order that!");
        }
        else if(!food.equals(array[2])){
            System.out.println("You cannot order that!");
        }
        else if(!food.equals(array[3])){
            System.out.println("You cannot order that!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Here is your" + food);
        }
    }
    }
```

Console:

```
What do you want for dinner? Your options are Beef, Pork, Chicken, and Cheesebugers. 
Beef(My input)
You cannot order that!
```

Comment: You have a logic problem. You'll never reach the last else part. Re-think your logic.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. After all other suggestions of course.

Answer (score 2):

**index of array stars from 0 not from 1**

Your array contains 4 elements ie array[0] to array[3]

Answer (score 1):

Use `!equals()` instead of != for comparing Strings in Java. Remember, `==` and `!=` is used to determine whether two object references point to the same object. `equals()` determines whether, in this case, whether two Strings are identical in terms of their character streams.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten this code a lot by using something like this:

```
if (Arrays.asList(array).contains(food)) { 
    System.out.println("Here is your " + food);
}
else { 
    System.out.println("You cannot order that!");
}
```

Also, it is good practice to use the equals() method to compare Strings instead of == which checks for object equality.

```
if (food.equals(array[1])) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `String`s with the `!=` operator, which means your're checking if they are the exact same instance in memory - which probably won't happen if you're inputting data from the console.

Instead, you should use `!food.equals(array[1])` to compare that the `String`s are not **equal** (as opposed to being the **same instance**).

Also, note that arrays in Java are zero based - the first element is in index 0, the second in index 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class scannerReview {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] array = new String[]{"Beef","Pork","Chicken","Cheeseburger"};
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What do you want for dinner? Your options are Beef, Pork, Chicken, and Cheesebugers. ");
        String food = sc.nextLine();
        if(food.equals(array[0])){
            System.out.println("Here is your" + food);
        } else if(food.equals(array[1])){
            System.out.println("Here is your" + food);
        } else if(food.equals(array[2])){
            System.out.println("Here is your" + food);
        } else if(food.equals(array[3])){
            System.out.println("Here is your" + food);
        } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot order that!");
        }
    }
    }
```